# Django po file is compiled like a mo file

Tags: django, po, mo

I'm a bit new to this translation system but as I understand it, .po files are the translation strings and the .mo files are the compiled translations from those. The problem that I'm having is that one of my .po files is filled with hex codes like a compiled .mo file and now when I run compilemessages I get an error on that file saying:

_djangojs.po:1: keyword "Mac" unknown

The word "Mac" does not exist in this file. Like I said, there are only hex characters in this. Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your translation somewhere else and regenerate your .po and .mo files, and then use msgmerge to bring the old .po translation into your newly generated .po file.